# Can't pass more than one argument using exec() PHP

Tags: php, exec

given the following code:

```
 exec('cmd /c c:\wamp\www\Telnetshutdown.py '.$router);
```

the router variable is passed fine.
but,
given the following code:

```
 exec('cmd /c c:\wamp\www\Telnetshutdown.py '.$router.' '.$interface);
```

or

```
 exec('cmd /c c:\wamp\www\Telnetshutdown.py '.$router." ".$interface);
```

or

```
         $zz=$router.' '.$interface;
 exec('cmd /c c:\wamp\www\Telnetshutdown.py '.$zz);
```

and more combinations of those..
Does not work!
How can I pass more than one argument?

Comment: Put double quotes around each of those arguments

Comment: but I want to pass the values thos parameters holds. double quotes will pass the literal "$router"..

Comment: Yes but you can put those double quotes in your string while still keeping the variable names out of it. It will still put double quotes around the final string

Comment: how can I do that? can you give me an example?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What's the final string that's run through `exec`?

Comment: `exec('cmd /c c:\wamp\www\Telnetshutdown.py "'.$router.'" "'.$interface.'"');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use escapeshellarg to make sure your arguments are properly escaped

It appears also based on [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101579) post that php will frame the argument passed to exec with `cmd /c "{{exec argument}}"` when passing it off to the shell.

Try this:

```
exec('c:\wamp\www\Telnetshutdown.py '.escapeshellarg($router).' '.escapeshellarg($interface));
```

Comment: updated answer to show the "don't strip my quotes" argument of cmd

Comment: also based on [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101579) it looks like you don't have to put in the `cmd /c` I guess on windows php puts in cmd /c "{{what you passed to exec}}"